# Concurrency Issue on IO operation

Tags: c#, .net, windows, concurrency, io

I'm writing a multi threaded console application which downloads pdf files from the web and copies it locally on to our content Server location(windows server). This is also the same location from which the files will be served to our website. 
I am skeptical about the approach, because of concurrrency issues such as if the user on the web site requests a pdf file from the content server, and at the same time the file is being written to or being updated by the console application there might be an IO Exception. (The application also makes updates to the pdf files if the original contents change over time)
Is there a way to control the concurrency issue?

Comment: How would the user know about the file before it has finished downloading by the console app?

Comment: well... the application runs multiple times and updates existing files based on updates to the original pdf's. So, if a user is accessing a particular file that the console app is trying to update, an IO Exception occurs and the file isn't updated

Comment: Regarding the downloads: you're better off downloading to one location and moving the file to another location where they can be later served after they are completely downloaded.

Comment: And why would an IOExcpetion being thrown be such a bad thing?

Comment: It is a bad thing in the sense that I would not be able to update the pdf if an exception is thrown. Is there a way i can make the thread wait for an IO Operation on a file to complete and then do its thing?

Comment: @kd7 I agree... I'm just too far in to the project to change things around now... But I am also going to consider that approach. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want your operations on creating and updating the files where they are served to be atomic, so that any other processes dealing with those files get the correct version, not the one that is still open for writing.

Instead of actually writing the files to where they will be served, you could write them to a temporary directory and then move them into the directory where they will be served from.

Similarly, for updating them, you should check that when your application is updating those pdfs that the files themselves are not changed until writing has finished. You could test this by making your application sleep after it has started writing to the file, for example.

Comment: I agree ... I hate to change the design at the stage that i am in this project, but I am for doing the right thing. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Better to change the design and fix some bugs than ship a product full of bugs that your end users will see, right? Hopefully your code isn't TOO tightly coupled to the locations you were going to be writing these files. If so, you might want to consider making these sorts of things easier to change. Put them in your application config, if you can.

Comment: yes...that's true! I am indeed storing all the location info in the app.config. I always try to get the right thing done even if it means a slightly late release...In this case anyway...I am writing all the files to a temp folder and after all the threads have finished processing, copying them all to their respective folder structure in the content server....I think that this would be a better approach. Any coments/suggstions??

Answer (score 1):

The details depend on which web server software you are using, but the key to this problem is to give each version of the file a different name.  The same URL, mind you, but a different name on the underlying file system.

Once a newer version of the file is ready, change the web server's configuration so that the URL points to the new file.  In any reasonably functional web server this should be an atomic operation.

If the web server doesn't have built-in support for this, you could serve the files via a custom server-side script.

Answer (score 0):

Mark the files hidden until the copy or update is complete.